# Term for the reference variable placeholder in a parameter list

Tags: java, c#, oop, methods, pass-by-reference

What is the proper term for the reference variable placeholder in a parameter list of a method?

```
public static void SomeMethod(objectType ???referenceVariablePlaceholder???)
```

Comment: parameter? or field i guess....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd call this the parameter name, unless I've misunderstood the question...

Edit: to better explain this, based on your comment, in the following code:

```
public void method(int a)...
```

I'd say `a` is the parameter name for the first (and only) parameter in the parameter list for method `method`.

If someone called it with:

```
method(2)
```

I'd call `2` the argument, which is set on parameter `a` in `method`.

If someone called it with:

```
int b = 2
method(b)
```

I'd say `b` is the argument name, and the argument's value is 2.

Comment: see my comment in response to dotctor - I assume your answer is the same?

Comment: I'd still call it a parameter name; in dotctor's quote, it's referring to the argument as being the value that populates the parameter, so if I have `method(int a)`, the parameter is called `a`. If someone calls it with `method(2)`, the *argument* is `2`.

Answer (score 1):

It is called **parameter** both in [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx) and [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

> The method definition specifies the names and types of any parameters
>   that are required. When calling code calls the method, it provides
>   concrete values called arguments for each parameter. The arguments
>   must be compatible with the parameter type but the argument name (if
>   any) used in the calling code does not have to be the same as the
>   parameter named defined in the method

---

> The parameter list in parenthesis—a comma-delimited list of input
>   parameters, preceded by their data types, enclosed by parentheses, ().
>   If there are no parameters, you must use empty parentheses.

Comment: i'm asking if there's a term for the name part of the parameter - perhaps just parameter name.  so for each parameter in the parameter list, ex. (int x, int y) - the int is the objectType and i'm asking if there's a term for the "x" and "y" - according to the top paragraph in your answer, it's "argument name"?

Answer (score 0):

It is called a "formal parameter".

The argument used in the **call** of the function is called an "actual parameter".